# docker run with --bip option fails

Tags: docker

Docker version:

```
Version: 1.12.2
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.7
Git commit: 8eab29e
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Docker info:

```
Storage Driver: btrfs
Build Version: Btrfs v4.1.2+20151002
Library Version: 101
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: oci
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.4.21-68-default
Operating System: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Issue:

```
docker config
/etc/sysconfig/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=0.0.0.0/0 --bip=127.12.7.1/24 --ip-forward=false --log-level=debug"

docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh
```

It fails with the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:334: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time=\\\\\\\"2016-10-27T20:51:30Z\\\\\\\" level=fatal msg=\\\\\\\"failed to set gateway while updating gateway: route for the gateway 127.12.7.1 could not be found: invalid argument\\\\\\\" \\\\n\\\"\"\n".
```

Note that with `--bip=172.17.0.1/16` (which is default) or if I remove the `--bip` option there is no such issue.

Anyone has seen this or has a suggestion?

Comment: Has docker created a bridge (probably `docker0`) with address the given ip address?

Comment: 172.17.0.1/16 was the default ip of docker0 (bridge) interface. However, I need to use another like 127.12.7.1/24 that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to remove this config from docker config.
`MountFlags=private` and restart docker service.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any other address. If the address starts with `127`, it is part of the `127.0.0.0/8` subnet and that is reserved for loopback purposes (as `127.0.0.1` is `localhost`).  Any other private address should work.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried restarting docker?

```
service docker restart
```

It solved my issue.

Comment: I saw that option in a github post, however it didn't work for me.

Comment: The question is clearly asking about an issue when configuring the docker daemon, and it's clearly being restarted (otherwise changing the `DOCKER_OPTS` variable wouldn't have any effect, and it clearly does according to the second to last sentence).